# How do I import a submodule with web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to do a dynamic import (using "__import__()") of a submodule in web2py and it doesn't seem to be finding the submodule.

Here's an example path:
web2py/app/modules/module.py <-- This works
web2py/app/modules/module_folder/submodule.py <-- This won't get spotted.

Right now as a workaround I'm using 'exec()' but I'd rather not do that.

---

**Answers to questions:**

*"Do you have __init__.py in module_folder?"*

Yep.

*"What exactly is the line of code you write to import web2py/app/modules/module_folder/submodule.py?"*

```
mapping_module = __import__('communication_templates.mappings.%s' % module_name)
```

*"what is the error?"*

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'module' object has no attribute 'mapping_dict'
```

Explanation: I'm trying to get a variable named 'mapping_dict' from the module once I've loaded it.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in `module_folder`? What exactly is the line of code you write to import `web2py/app/modules/module_folder/submodule.py`? And what is the error?

Comment: @zvone I've answered your questions in the original post because I can't create newlines here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `__import__` does not do the most intuitive thing (neither does `import` btw).

Here's what happens:

```
>>> import sys
>>> x = __import__('package1.package2.module')
>>> x
<module 'package1' from 'C:\\Temp\\package1\\__init__.py'>
```

Even though `package1.package2.module` was imported, the variable returned is actually `package1`.

So, to access something that is in `package1.package2.module`, one has to dig down again:

```
>>> x.package2.module.Class
<class 'package1.package2.module.Class'>
```

**Is it then the same as importing just `package1`?**

Not really:

```
>>> x = __import__('package1')
>>> x
<module 'package1' from 'C:\\Temp\\package1\\__init__.py'>
>>> x.package2.module.Class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'package1' has no attribute 'package2'
```

### Why?

Well, `__import__` is the same as `import, that is, these are the same:

```
package1 = __import__('package1.package2.module')
# is the same as:
import package1.package2.module
```

And:

```
package1 = __import__('package1')
# is the same as:
import package1
```

In each of those cases, you get just one local variable `package1`.

In the case of importing `package1.package2.module`, `package2` is also imported and stored in `package2` attribute of package `package1` etc.

## Solution

To access `package1.package2.module.Class`, if `package1.package2.module` is in a string:

```
>>> s = 'package1.package2.module'
>>> module = __import__(s)
>>> for submodule_name in s.split('.')[1:]:
...     module = getattr(module, submodule_name)
...
>>> module.Class
<class 'package1.package2.module.Class'>
```